# Difference in Classification Model output after input image preprocessing with torch.transforms and OpenCV

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, opencv, multiclass-classification, pytorch-dataloader, python

I finetuned a resnet50 classification model in PyTorch. during training, torch. transforms was used for preprocessing of images. When I perform the inference using the same preprocessing in OpenCV, I am not getting the same output. Kindly help me figure out the issue.

Torch.transforms preprocessing:

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]
)

OpenCV preprocessing:


def preprocess_image(image):
    ## swap the color channels from BGR to RGB, resize it, and scale
    ## the pixel values to [0, 1] range
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    image = image.astype("float32") / 255.0
    ## subtract ImageNet mean, divide by ImageNet standard deviation,
    ## set "channels first" ordering, and add a batch dimension
    image -= [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
    image /= [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
    image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))
    image = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
    ### return the preprocessed image
    return image
```

Answer (score 0):

The `transforms.Resize()` method uses by default the INTERPOLATION mode `InterpolationMode.BILINEAR`, whereas your OpenCV code uses `interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC`.

You should use `cv2.resize(interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)`.

Also, it might be suitable to take a look at this thread: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/difference-between-pil-resize-and-opencv-resize/33138

Otherwise the `transforms.Normalize()` operation you are using is correct, since the order of the parameters is `mean` (which is subtracted) and `std_dev` (to whom the subtraction result is divided).

Finally, I assume that you operate `np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))` in order to have the same order in both `OpenCV` and `PyTorch` preprocessing `(channels,height,width)`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I have tried INTER_AREA interpolation as well. but unable to get the same model output. i used PIL for this purpose and was able to get the same model output. My problem is that I have to implement opencv function in C++, so I have to get openCV preprocessing to work in this case,,,

Comment: Why don't you use INTER_LINEAR in OpenCV? Why do you use INTER_AREA when you know exactly that PIL uses BILINEAR interpolation? It makes no sense to switch to INTER_AREA instead of INTER_CUBIC, you should rather change to INTER_LINEAR in OpenCV if you want to get closer to your desired result.

Comment: I updated the answer so that you can better understand.

Comment: sorry i mean i have tried bilinear interpolation ie INTER_LINEAR in open cv, but couldn't get the same result

Comment: PIL resize function and opencv resize function with bilinear interpolation is different. are you familiar with this problem ?

Comment: If there isn't any exact match like you mention, then you cannot fully reproduce the results, unless you reimplement it yourself

Comment: Secondly, we have the cv2.INTER_LINEAR method, which performs bilinear interpolation — this is the method that OpenCV uses by default when resizing images. The general idea behind bilinear interpolation can be found in any elementary school math textbook — slope-intercept form: (taken from here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/01/20/opencv-resize-image-cv2-resize/)

Comment: If you don't get the exact results, then maybe there really is a difference between their backbone implementation, but by default without implementing on your own, I believe my answer is the closest to your needs.

Comment: You can also have a look at this thread: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/difference-between-pil-resize-and-opencv-resize/33138

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions,, i have taken a look at the discuss pytorch thread you shared. it appears that it is a big issue than I expected.